# can't remove an event listener I attached

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I have attached an event listener in a module using

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => this.clickCatcherFunction(target_id));
```

but when that function is executed, the line

```
document.removeEventListener("keydown", () => this.clickCatcherFunction());
```

doesn't remove the listener.  Next time a key is pressed it executes the clickCatcherFunction and fails.  How can I pass it the same function I used to create it to remove it?

other failed attempts:

```
document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.clickCatcherFunction());
document.removeEventListener("keydown", clickCatcherFunction());
document.removeEventListener("keydown", clickCatcherFunction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only named functions can be removed, not anonymous functions because even if you make an identical anonymous function, it won't be the exact same ***instance*** of the function you had previously added. You'll have to set up your function separately, like this:

```
function clickCather(evt){
  .  .  .
}
```

Then you can add and remove it with `addEventListener("click", clickCatcher)` and `removeEventListener("click", clickCatcher);` because you'll be referring to the same function instance in memory.

And, note that with both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` you don't invoke your function (no parenthesis at the end of the function name), you only want to refer to it.

Comment: yup, how I added it is the problem.